# Sorting Multiple Collections vs Subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm new on MongoDB also in nodejs. So sorry if I'm asking a simple question but I'm just creating the structure so It's the best time to change.

### My current structure (subdocumented):

```
 var Channels = new Schema({
        _id: {type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Channel'},
        type: {type: String, default: ''},
        subscriber: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        Points: {type: Number, default: 0},
        mPoints: {type: Number, default: 0},
        lastSeen: {type: Date, default: Date.now() }
    });


    var ViewerSchema = new Schema({
        _id:  Number,
        name: String,
        displayName: String,
        Channels: [Channels]
    });

    var Viewer = mongoose.model('Viewer', ViewerSchema, 'Viewers');
```

From that point here what I'm planning to do with it.

Sorting by `Viewer.Channels[id].mPoints`, It's like sorting by monthly points for single channel. (id is constant)

### Simple example:

```
{
    "_id" : 46761135,
    "name" : "h4ckhers",
    "displayName" : "h4ckhers",
    "Channels" : [
        {
            "_id" : 46761135,
            "mPoints" : 0,
            "Points" : 0,
            "subscriber" : false,
            "type" : "mod"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 37259814,
            "mPoints" : 0,
            "Points" : 0,
            "subscriber" : false,
            "type" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : 71978007,
            "mPoints" : 10,
            "Points" : 0,
            "subscriber" : true,
            "type" : null
        }
],
    "__v" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : 144771688,
    "name" : "sevo",
    "displayName" : "sevo",
    "Channels" : [
        {
            "_id" : 71978007,
            "mPoints" : 5,
            "Points" : 0,
            "subscriber" : false,
            "type" : null
        }
],
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : 43354629,
    "name" : "son1903",
    "displayName" : "Son1903",
    "Channels" : [
        {
            "_id" : 71978007,
            "mPoints" : 9,
            "Points" : 0,
            "subscriber" : false,
            "type" : null
        }
],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

When I use `Viewer.Channels['71978007'].mPoint` It should output like (h4ckhers, Son1903, sevo). How can I do it and should I use multiple documents for that and how should they indexed if they should. ( I want to handle it in mongodb not in javascript if It's an option)

Note: Every viewer will have maximum 100 channels. (But It's likely that viewers will have maximum 15-20 and avarage 5-8 channels in real world)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution my self. Here is my query:

```
db.Viewers.find( { "Channels._id": 71978007 } ).sort( { "Channels.mPoints": -1 } )
```

My index:

```
db.Viewers.createIndex( { "Channels._id": 1, "Channels.mPoints": -1 } )
```

Used index for this query: `Channels._id_1_Channels.mPoints_-1`

Referance: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

---

## Old partial solution:

I found this query, this is doing the thing but I still wonder about performance.

```
 db.Viewers.aggregate([
 {$unwind:"$Channels"},
 {$match:{"Channels._id":71978007}},
 {$sort:{"Channels.mPoints":-1}}])
```

I created this index for that query:

```
db.Viewers.createIndex( { "Channels._id": 1, "Channels.mPoints": -1 } )
```

But when I use

```
db.Viewers.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] ).pretty()
```

Response is:

```
{
    "name" : "Channels._id_1_Channels.mPoints_-1",
    "key" : {
        "Channels._id" : 1.0,
        "Channels.mPoints" : -1.0
    },
    "host" : "Hackhers:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0),
        "since" : ISODate("2017-01-21T18:46:53.764Z")
    }
}
```